# Using lambdas to extract an Object attribute contained in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, java-8

I have made a class called `User` with two string attributes: `Login` and `Password`.

I have a database (`userList`, of type `ArrayList<User>`) with all the existing users, and I want to know if a login is already used or not.

I tried to use lambda expressions in order to do that, but it doesn't work:

```
ArrayList<String> loginList = null;
userListe.forEach(x->loginList.add(x.getLogin()));
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: What does _it doesn't work_ mean? What did you expect that code to do? Why and what did it do instead?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `userListe` is a `List`:

```
List<String> loginList = userListe
             .stream()
             .map(x -> x.getLogin())
             .collect(Collectors.toList));
```

Explanation:

It is better to use a `List` instead of `ArrayList` because it is always preferable using interface instead of concrete types. First, using a `stream` you create a flow of `User` objects. Using `map` you get a field from your objects using the appropriate getter. At last, using a `collect` you can collect all objects returned by map method, in this case `String` object.

Your `loginList` is `null`, so the first `forEach` will throw a `NullPointerException`. Also, remember that it is better to have pure function in lambdas, with no side effects. Using `stream` and `collect` allows you to get a `List` of objects you need without having functions with side effects.

Comment: Or `User::getLogin`.